# Issue with paging and sorting on class with many-to-one reference

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have an API endpoint that takes in a polygon shape on a map and returns a list of businesses within that shape. This is what the method looks like which does the search:

```
@Query(value="SELECT i FROM IntakeProperty i WHERE ST_WITHIN(i.address.point, (:searchArea)) = true")
Page<IntakeProperty> findAllByPolygon(@Param("searchArea") Polygon searchArea, Pageable pageable);
```

The data comes back on the front end just fine, however the issue lies in sorting the data.

There are a number of properties on this IntakeProperty entity, and one of them is a list of IntakeLeaseTransactions. These lease transactions hold a majority of the information, which comes up on the front end, relating to the property. IntakeProperty has a One To Many relationship with IntakeLeaseTransaction.

Setting the polygon aside for a moment, if I do a normal search for all the properties with a regular findAll(Pageable) call, I'm able to sort by all the properties shown: those coming from the IntakeProperty directly and its related IntakeLeaseTransaction. When I use my custom query, however, I'm only able to sort the data by the columns that are directly on IntakeProperty. When I want to sort by a column on the related IntakeLeaseTransaction entity, I get an error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [intakeprop0_.id.intakeLeaseTransactions] with element property reference [tenantNetRentableArea] [SELECT i FROM com.ldt.domain.IntakeProperty i WHERE ST_WITHIN(i.address.point, (:searchArea)) = true order by i.intakeLeaseTransactions.tenantNetRentableArea asc];
```

That's the template, just replace tenantNetRentableArea with whatever property from IntakeLeaseTransaction that I'm trying to sort by, and that's the error that I'll get.

If I'm understanding the error, the issue is that IntakeLeaseTransaction in the IntakeProperty is a List, and it can't know which element from that list to grab the field that it needs to sort by, even if there's only 1 item in the list.

How can I solve this while keeping IntakeLeaseTransaction as type List on the IntakeProperty class?